# 876925431=2016 Use the four basic operators

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Use the four basic operators ×, ÷, +, − and if you want brackets to make:

8 _ 7 _ 6 _ 9 _ 2 _ 5 _ 4 _ 3 _ 1 = 2016.

You can use each operator as many times as needed. Concatenation is not allowed.

Comment: Is each operator to be used exactly once?

Comment: Is concatenation allowed?

Comment: no, you can use operators as much as u want

Comment: concatenation is not allowed

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Exhange Puzzleing. You have to tag people to reply, unless it is on their post

Comment: @Deusovi I'm tagging you as oklahoma95 forgot to tag you when replying to your question.

Comment: @hexonimo I'm tagging you as oklahoma95 forgot to tag you when replying to your question.

Comment: Also, puzzles where there are so many answers where one is not better/worse than any other is generally frowned upon in Puzzling.SE

Answer (score 7):

I tried a computer program to solve this problem.

I got 425 different expressions giving 2016.

So I added restrictions.  I used only addition and multiplication.  I stil get 26 expressions.  You'll find them below.

> $8*7*(6+9+2*(5+4)+3*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+9+2*(5+4)+3)*1 = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+9*2+5+(4+3)*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+9*2+5+4+3*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+9*2+5+4+3)*1 = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+9*2+(5+4+3)*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+9+(2*(5+4)+3)*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+(9+2*(5+4)+3)*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7*(6+(9*2+5+4+3)*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7+(6*9+2)*5*(4+3*1) = 2016$
>  $8*7+(6*9+2)*5*(4+3)*1 = 2016$
>  $8*(7+6+9*2+5)*(4+3*1) = 2016$
>  $8*(7+6+9*2+5)*(4+3)*1 = 2016$
>  $8*(7+((6+9)*2+5)*(4+3*1)) = 2016$
>  $8*(7+((6+9)*2+5)*(4+3)*1) = 2016$
>  $8*(7+((6+9)*2+5)*(4+3))*1 = 2016$
>  $8*(7*((6+9)*2+5)+4+3*1) = 2016$
>  $8*(7*((6+9)*2+5)+(4+3)*1) = 2016$
>  $8*(7*((6+9)*2+5)+4+3)*1 = 2016$
>  $8*((7+6)*9*2+5+4*3+1) = 2016$
>  $(8+7+6)*((9*2+5)*4+3+1) = 2016$
>  $(8+7*(6*9+2))*5+4*(3+1) = 2016$
>  $(8+(7*(6+9+2)+5)*4)*(3+1) = 2016$
>  $(8+((7+6)*9+2+5)*4)*(3+1) = 2016$
>  $(8*7+6*9+2)*(5+4*3+1) = 2016$
>  $(8*7+(6*9+2)*5*(4+3))*1 = 2016$
>
>  Note that over half of the solutions are just variations of the placement of the '*1'.

To answer the question about "no brackets" and "not ending in a product":

> I found no solution without brackets.
>
>   But the solution
>   $((8+7)*6+9+2)*5*4-3-1 = 2016$
>   doesn't need any bracket if we ignore operator precedence.
>   It can be computed on an old calculator just typing the operations from left to right.
>
>   It is also one of 12 expressions I found that doesn't end in a product or quotient.

Comment: Without brackets?

Comment: I found no solution without brackets.

Comment: Did you find anything that isn't a product, i.e. last operation to be executed is multiplication? (I didn't, but I'm not a computer.)

Comment: @PaulPanzer I believe you can turn the last one here into a quotient (also the second one and the fifth one, if you wish).

Comment: @WhatsUp Quotient is technically a product ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This works:

> 8 x 7 x 6 x 9 / ( - 2 + 5 ) x (4 - 3 + 1)

or

> 8 x 7 x 6 x 9 / ((2 x 5 ) - 4) x (3 + 1)

or

> 8 x (7 - 6) x 9 x ( - 2 + 5 + 4) x (3 + 1)

or

> (8 - 7 + 6) x 9 x (((2 + 5 + 4) x 3) - 1)

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few:

> $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3-1 = 2+0+1*6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3-1 = 2+0*1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3-1 = 2+0/1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3-1 = 2-0+1*6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3-1 = 2-0*1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3-1 = 2-0/1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3*1 = 2+0+1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3*1 = 2-0+1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3/1 = 2+0+1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9+2-5*4-3/1 = 2-0+1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2-5*4-3+1 = 2*0+1*6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2-5*4-3+1 = 2*0*1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2-5*4-3+1 = 2*0/1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2-5*4-3*1 = 2*0-1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2-5*4-3/1 = 2*0-1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2*5-4*3+1 = 2+0+1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2*5-4*3+1 = 2-0+1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2*5-4*3-1 = 2+0-1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2*5-4*3-1 = 2-0-1+6$
>  $8+7+6+9-2*5-4*3-1 = 2*0+1+6$

And very many more.

There are $2,762$ solutions in this form (without using parentheses).

Comment: Taking the no concatenation a step further, but technically correct, I guess :)

Comment: I think 2016 was supposed to remain a single number.

Comment: @FlorianF At the time the question was posted there was no clarification as to where the operators were meant to be placed. The underscores were not there originally.

Comment: I see.  I thought it was a curious choice to split the 2016 but given the original question that makes perfectly sense.

Comment: @FlorianF Original wording is "Add the four basic operators ×÷+− and optionally brackets to: 876925431 To get the total 2016." which is pretty unambiguous IMO.

Comment: @PaulPanzer "876925431 to get the total 2016" was on a line by itself so I felt it wasn't too unreasonable to assume I could add the operators anywhere within that line of text. It was not clearly stated otherwise, so these solutions are valid (until the problem was clarified).

Comment: @DenverCoder1 Probably not worth it getting too het up about, but leaving typographic subtleties to one side as far as I can tell (not a native speaker, though) just in terms of grammar there is only one way of reading this.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

> `8*7*9*4+3*1-2-6+5`
>  Note that I didn't keep the original order of the digits.

This is how I arrived at it:

> *2016 is a lot bigger than single-digit numbers, so we need multiplication to get big*
>  `8*7*6*9*2*5*4*3*1`
>  **362880**
>  *This is approximately 150 times too big. We will want to divide by 150. `150 = 2*3*5*5`. Let us divide by `5*5`*
>  `8*7*6*9*2/5*4*3*1`
>  **14515.199999999999**
>  *Then divide by 3*
>  `8*7*6*9*2/5*4+3+1`
>  **4842.4**
>  *Now divide by 2*
>  `8*7*6*9/5*4+3+1+2`
>  **2425.2**
>  *This too big by 400, let's try replacing `*6/5` with `*5/6`*
>  `8*7/6*9*5*4+3+1+2`
>  **1686.0**
>  *This is too small by 400. The average of `6/5` and `5/6` is approximately 1, let's remove 5 and 6 from the product.*
>  `8*7*9*4+3+1+2+6+5`
>  **2033**
>  This is close! We need to remove 17. `17 = 6+6 + 2+2 + 1`
>  `8*7*9*4+3*1-2-6+5`
>  **2016**

Comment: You shouldnot change the order of digits